# Term for police seal on door

Tags: single-word-requests

The police and other authorities sometimes seal the door to a crime scene or similar with an adhesive seal. Here is an example from Germany, where it is called a "Verschlusssiegel", literally a 'closing seal':

[image: Verschlusssiegel in Berlin]

What is this called in English? Either officially (the technical term) or colloquially.

Answer (score 3):

Believe it or not, it's actually called a **seal.**

The point of a seal is to close something and provide evidence that it's been subsequently opened. This happens with wax seals, with gummed envelopes, and it's the same here. Either the seal is torn, or layers within it separate so there is evidence that it was once stuck to the doorframe.

Here's an advertising image from a manufacturer (Biffar) showing it's what they call them:

[image: Screenshot via Google image search]

Note that different seals might be identified differently. This one is labelled "Crime scene" so they promote it as "Crime Scene Seal". However premises might be sealed for any purpose, including (for example) by executors if the property is part of someone's estate after their death. The generic name is simply *seal.*

Comment: I never knew this was a "thing". Did you come across any qualifying words, like restricted access seal, or anti-tamper seal? Never mind, I see you've mentioned a crime scene seal.

Comment: In my experience, qualifying words describe the type of the seal itself (anti-tamper seals are readily available; that's an image of a crime scene seal, etc). A restricted access seal would be a seal to which access is restricted, not one which restricts access [all seals do that!] so it wouldn't occur very often.

Comment: The "seal" by Biffar is not a seal they sell to police or other authorities, but an advertising campaign. If you read the text on the image you have provided, it says that for this campaign, which was designed by Ogilvy & Mather, "[a]dhesive stickers, strikingly similar to police crime scene seals, were being placed on house and apartment entrance doors in affluent neighborhoods" to "make people go through the experience of what it's like not to have a safe front door" to convince house and apartment owners "of the benefits of the especially safe front doors made by Biffar".

Comment: Here's a link to a larger image with legible text: http://www.adeevee.com/aimages/200711/03/biffar-doors-germany-doors-crime-scene-seal-outdoor-305810-adeevee.jpg

Comment: @Fredbob it's still called a seal. It certainly is *not* barricade tape or crime scene tape, which is not adhesive and used to mark off a substantial area (strung between lamp-posts, for example).

Comment: If I look at real seals of this type (see examples in my answer), I don't quite believe that those authorities buy them from some manufacturer. They look printed by the police on colored adesive paper.

Comment: Well, we can't tell that from the Berlin photograph. Similar things do exist in the UK, but I'd need to go and find one to photograph. I couldn't find one online.

Comment: I understand that it's called a "seal". But what kind of seal? A garage door is a door, sure, but more specifically it's a "garage door". A "seal on the door" could be a sign with the seal (= emblem) of the agency residing within, but a "coroner's seal on the door" is unmistakeable.

Comment: @fredbob I don't believe you've read my answer, particularly the second paragraph.

Comment: I have, and I know what a seal is. I just don't believe the term for what I mean is "seal" – which is why searching for "seal" doesn't turn up any related results (while "coroner's seal" does).

Comment: If you’re still looking for a photo from the uk: https://windsorstar.com/news/local-news/windsor-police-say-womans-sudden-death-on-weekend-now-a-homicide

Comment: @Laurel Not really, I'm afraid: that's Windsor, Ontario. (What I meant about finding one was just that: finding one. I'm sure I can ask some colleagues...)

Comment: Oops I thought it was the one in the uk

Answer (score 2):

It seems as if terminology varies.

In L.A. the seal for a crime scene is called a "coroner's seal", though a "public administrator seal" [also exists](http://mec.lacounty.gov/wps/portal/mec/ourservices/forlandlords?1dmy&page=dept.mec.ourservices.forlandlords.detail.hidden&urile=wcm%3apath%3a/me-coroner+content/mec+site/home/our+services/for+landlords+and+property+owners/75cbc9fd-9fa6-41ff-b9f5-b452a9c41cb4):

[image]

In N.Y. it is a "seal for door of d.o.a. premises":

[image]

I was unable to find anything like these seals for the UK. Maybe they don't exist there?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like most merchants call it ["barricade tape"](https://www.bing.com/shop?q=police+seal+tape&FORM=SHOPTB). The idea of barricading, "[preventing or delaying movement](https://www.bing.com/search?q=define%20barricade&pc=MOZI&form=MOZSBR)," fits in line with the German root word, *verschluss*, which means [to lock, stop, or fasten](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/german-english/verschluss).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, what you refer to is not a seal as that shown in my question, but a *tape*. See https://www.google.com/search?q=police+tape

Comment: Yes, I think Andrew's answer about **seal** is a term for that specific seal. But, a "seal" does not convey the full sense of the german term. Maybe **barricade seal**? lol